# Spring JPA with Hibernate: How to verify that an object was saved?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, save

How can you verify that after, for example,  UserService object called save(User entity) (CrudRepository implementation) method in UserRepository object (annotated with @Repository("userRepository")), that object was indeed saved and there were no issues.

Almost all the tutorials simply tend to ignore this situation and make save(User user) method in a service class void.

Comment: Other (maybe better and commonly accepted) approaches exist. Such, You polemise: " let lthow exceptions when required. Catch in places, You can make some good decisions."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a **integration test** for that, using the H2 memory database.

The code will be like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class UserInsertTest {

    @AutoWired
    private UserService userService;

    @AutoWired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void insert() {
        UserEntity user = userService.save(new UserEntity());
        assertNotNull(userRepository.findOne(user.getId());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you also please tell me why in most of the tutorials authors implement save method as void in a service class? Basically it makes impossible to verify the result like in your example.

Comment: I can't say if this is so common. It's important to return the entity (or the representation of your User class in your application) because in save process the saved user can have new informations (like: creation date, the `id`, etc) that are important for who called the method. And is way easier to test the method :)

Comment: Accepted, but this not good, genereal, answer. Rather 'add some code because algorithm isn't good designed'

Comment: Jacek, your suggestion was a more general answer. But it also was in a right direction and quite helpful so I upvoted it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How I do it is create a wrapper class which contains just a boolean value.

```
parseSaveUserResponse(userDao.save(user))

private SaveUserResponse parseSaveUserResponse(final User user) {
        return new SaveUserResponse(user != null);
  }
```

Here I have create a wrapper class which will have its field true if the save was successful.This is a good practice if we are exposing our apis.

Comment: jpa save method never will return null

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@Service
public class RepositoryWrapper {

    public <T, ID> boolean save(JpaRepository<T, ID> jpaRepository, T t, Function<T, ID> getIdFunc) {
        jpaRepository.save(t);
        return jpaRepository.existsById(getIdFunc.apply(t));
    }

    public <T, ID> boolean delete(JpaRepository<T, ID> jpaRepository, ID id) {
        jpaRepository.deleteById(id);
        return !jpaRepository.existsById(id);
    }

}
```

And use.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryWrapper repositoryWrapper;

    @PostMapping("/my")
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(User user) {
        // Check parameter...

        if(repsitoryWrapper.save(userRepository, user, _user -> _user.getId())) {
            // Success
        }
        else {
            // Fail
        }
    }
}
```